# Library was not found for -lGoogleToolboxForMac for integration of Gmail SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I am new to iOS,I am getting  error:

> ld :Library was not found for -lGoogleToolboxForMac

when I add **libGoogleToolboxForMac** to Link Binary With Library as well as for **libGTMSessionFetcher** and **libGTMOAuth2**

I used **cocoapods** in the project from https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating

I tried the below solutions:

1. **Build Active Architecture only** From **NO** to **Yes**
2. Removed **Library Search Path**

Comment: did you opened the xcworkspace after running `pod install` ?

Comment: yes ,opened xcworkspace after running `pod install` but still getting the error

Comment: don't remove the library search path after the pod install. and please check is there any warning given in the pod install.

Comment: I don't find any warnings during pod install and add the library search path

Comment: I did it again (pod install in the project) I found some warnings like this in Terminal {Project name [Debug]` target overrides the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Project name/Pods-Project name.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation }
- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

Comment: so use `$(inherited)` variable in your framework search path. actually your project is building with it's own search path, but now your project is under a workspace, so search path in the workspace should also be included in the project file, to do that, easiest way is to add the `$(inherited)` variable in your delcaration.

Comment: i had done that but still getting the Error `ld: library not found for -lGTMOAuth2
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: Thanks for your help Mr. Ratul Shaker .Finally I solved

Answer (score 0):

For anyone getting this error, I thought I'd post how I *finally* solved it...

First I removed the platform and re-install a fresh version as I had made lots of desperate changes to try to fix this.  So, that is (since I'm using Ionic, but could just be "cordova platform..."):

```
> ionic cordova platform rm ios
> ionic cordova platform add ios
```

Then I needed to make sure the pods were installed correctly.  Open a terminal window in the platforms/ios folder, and type:

```
> pod install
```

Next build the iOS version of the app:

```
> ionic cordova build ios
```

This gave errors, but I kept going...  Finally, I opened the Workspace file (not project file) in XCode.  I selected the correct certificates and built.  Then archived.  Everything worked great.

I hope this helps someone else.